# Returning result of SqlCommand in class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

As I'm not programming long time I would like to ask you if there is way to call result of this SqlCommand which is in class called `klientClass`

I was thinking that it could look something like this:

```
private static void ReadFirma()
    {
        string queryString =
            "SELECT rocnik from FIRMA;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnection.DataSource.ConnectionString
                   ))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            int result= Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            try
            {

            }
            finally
            {

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Because I need to insert this result into my report parameter here:

```
 this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(this.prehled_zajezdu.HereReturnResult);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I'm sorry for quiet low-quality question, hope not to receive down-votes.

Comment: You can use dataset or datatable fill by using DataAdapter.

Comment: i don't understand the question. can you be more clear about it? yes you can run this function and you can call it, what doesn't work for you?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Well I'm not sure how can I call exactly the result of the SqlCommand, would you help me pleasE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you need to use the result? Your question is lacking in describing what you want to achieve. A TableAdapter takes either a DataTable or a DataSet as argument to the Fill method. In order to get a scalar, you don't need a DataReader. The ReadFirma method should probably return something.

Comment: see this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993211/how-to-fill-datatable-with-sql-table

Comment: @PHeiberg I meant to return the result in this: this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(this.prehled_zajezdu.HereReturnResult);

Comment: Do you understand that we do NOT know what `prehled_zajezdu` is? You want ReadFirma to create a class object or what? It's not returning anything..

Comment: @Tarec sorry this is Method in class named klientClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can retrieve and use the value from the database in your `Fill` method (provided that the Fill method takes an argument of the type `int` and that the `myConnection` field is available from the static method)

```
private static int ReadFirma()
{
    string queryString = "SELECT rocnik from FIRMA";
    using (var connection = 
        new SqlConnection(myConnection.DataSource.ConnectionString))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}


void SomeMethod()
{
    this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(ReadFirma());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood exactly what I meant even that I described that very badly. May I ask how do I call this ReadFirma() to another class where is klint Tableadapter.Fill pleasE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got that I set only private static int to public static int. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable object for your Goal.

```
private static DataTable ReadFirma()
{
    string queryString = "SELECT rocnik from FIRMA";
    using (var connection = 
        new SqlConnection(myConnection.DataSource.ConnectionString))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}


void SomeMethod()
{
    this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(ReadFirma());
}
```