# C# list<string> in a list<string>[] .toList()

Tags: c#, list, tostring, mysql-connector

I am currently learning how to use database connections and how to read and write data. I am using Mysql data/connector 6.1 for visual studio. This supports access to a localhost mysql server.

I want to display personal information of the person logged in for which i use this code:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE id='" + id + "'";

List<string>[] list = new List<string>[5];
list[0] = new List<string>();
list[1] = new List<string>();
list[2] = new List<string>();
list[3] = new List<string>();
list[4] = new List<string>();


if (this.openConnection() == true)
{

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    //Een nieuw datareader object maken en dan query uitvoeren
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        list[0].Add(dataReader["id"].ToString());
        list[1].Add(dataReader["voornaam"].ToString());
        list[2].Add(dataReader["achternaam"].ToString());
        list[3].Add(dataReader["geboortedatum"].ToString());
        list[4].Add(dataReader["Rol_id"].ToString());
    }

    dataReader.Close();

    this.closeConnection();

    return list;
}
```

I use Lists because I am following this tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)

Then when i return the list i want to get that data and add it to labels on my winform. this is the code i use:

```
DBconnect connectDB = new DBconnect();
List<string>[] persGegevens = connectDB.persoonlijkeGegevens(userId);
for (int i = 0; i <= persGegevens.Count(); i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            lblVoornaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i].ToString();
            break;
        case 2:
            lblAchternaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i].ToString();
            break;
        case 3:
            lblGbrtedatumVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i].ToString();
            break;
        case 4:
            lblFuntieVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i].ToString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But unfortunatly the code does not convert the data in List toString but the element will get converted toString. This is what i get: system.collections.generic.list`1[system.string]
I also tried to do this with a foreach but that did not work because i can't specify which element has to be placed in what label.

Do you guys know what is the problem here? and is this the right way to retrieve data? or should i use something else to store my data?

Comment: Use a DataTable to make your code easier to work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993211/how-to-fill-datatable-with-sql-table

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Never has using a DataTable for something like this made anything easier, in my experience

Comment: I would recommending looking into using Entity Framework and Linq it may make things a little easier for you to understand.

Comment: You should be using MySqlCommand parameters and not passing in `id` directly to the string.  Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think nik0lias suggestion is formerly correct but maybe it can runs as desired if changed to :

```
    case 1:
        lblVoornaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][ 0 ].ToString();
        break;
    case 2:
        lblAchternaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][ 0 ].ToString();
        break;
    case 3:
        lblGbrtedatumVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][ 0 ].ToString();
        break;
    case 4:
        lblFuntieVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][ 0 ].ToString();
```

If I am right, consider if a List array List<>[] is needed or you can simplify your code with List this way:

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE id='" + id + "'";

    List<string> listGebruiker = new List<string>();


    if (this.openConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Een nieuw datareader object maken en dan query uitvoeren
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            listGebruiker.Add(dataReader["id"].ToString());
            listGebruiker.Add(dataReader["voornaam"].ToString());
            listGebruiker.Add(dataReader["achternaam"].ToString());
            listGebruiker.Add(dataReader["geboortedatum"].ToString());
            listGebruiker.Add(dataReader["Rol_id"].ToString());
        }

        dataReader.Close();

        this.closeConnection();

        return list;
    }
```

and

```
    DBconnect connectDB = new DBconnect();
    List<string> persGegevens = connectDB.persoonlijkeGegevens(userId);

    lblVoornaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[1];
    lblAchternaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[2];
    lblGbrtedatumVrbl.Text = persGegevens[3];
    lblFuntieVrbl.Text = persGegevens[4];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It might indeed be a better solution to not use a list<> array but to use list. I did not think about that because i was following a tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a `ToString()` on a list, hence the output.  You need to specify where in the array or list you want to display and do a `ToString()` on.  The below will work or you could use another variable to loop through each user to get their details.

```
DBconnect connectDB = new DBconnect();
    List<string>[] persGegevens = connectDB.persoonlijkeGegevens(userId);
    for (int i = 0; i <= persGegevens.Count(); i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                lblVoornaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][0].ToString();
                break;
            case 2:
                lblAchternaamVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][1].ToString();
                break;
            case 3:
                lblGbrtedatumVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][2].ToString();
                break;
            case 4:
                lblFuntieVrbl.Text = persGegevens[i][3].ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This indeed works, I use PersGegevens[i][0] because every list on list<string>[] only has 1 element. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`persGegevens[i]` is of type `List<string>`, so `persGegevens[i].ToString()` wont give anything meaningful. You need something like:

```
persGegevens[i][j];
```